# passing a batch variable to a script with the same variable

Tags: batch-file, imagemagick

I need help with this question as I don't know how to ask it.
I have a batch script in imageMagick
`magick %1 -resize 4096x4096 %1`
I want to resize the image but I don't want to overwrite the original.  so I would like to put a prefix in the name like 4K_
something like this
`magick image.jpg -resize 4096x4096 4k_image.jpg`
I tried things like

```
set a = %1
set b = 4k_
set c = %a%%b%
magick %1 -resize 4096x4096 %c%
```

I think the problem is because imageMagic takes "image%03.jpg" as an so it gets stuck on "%"
is there anyway to get around this or can imageMagic add prefixes?
Thanks for the help

ps I found this but I need it to work for 1 file and I don't know what the suffix will be.

`for %I in ( *.png ) do magick "%I" -set filename: "small_%t" -resize 50% "%[filename:].png"`
I think I want it more like this

```
magick %1 -set filename: "small_%t" -resize 50% "%[filename:]"
```

but of course that doesn't work

Comment: Do you mean like this: `@magick "%~1" -resize 4096x4096 "4k_%~1"`?

Comment: Off topic note: In a batch file you'll find that `image%03.jpg` doesn't work! You'd have to change that to `image%%03.jpg`. Essentially your issue was unrelated to the `%` character.

Comment: If you want to continue to use unnecessary variables, your syntax is wrong, they're creating variables names with trailing whitespece, and values with leading whitespace. You should use this recommended syntax, `@Set "a=%~1"`, `@Set "b=4k_"`, and `@Set "c=%a%%b%"`. Then you could use `@magick "%a%" -resize 4096x4096 "%c%"`.

Answer (score 0):

got it! thanks Compo

`magick %1 -set filename: "4k_%%f" -resize 4096x4096 "%%[filename:]"`